# Body effect of input pair differential transistor?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I would like to know how we connect Body of differential nmos input pair? Generally we want VSB to be zero to avoid vth variation. In input pair case, we have source not tied to gnd, so there will be a VTH variation right? I see a general practice of connecting bulk to lowest potential in this case (GND).

Just want to understand, what is the idea behind connecting

1. Body to Gnd for diff nmos input pair,
2. Body and source shorted for differential nmos input pair.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the NMOS input pair both options of connecting the bulk terminal to source or ground are used in designs. Connecting it to ground will increase the VTH of both the input pair transistors. So, the VTH variation happening due to body bias is expected to get cancelled because it affects both transistors equally.

Following explanation is assuming that your question is w.r.t IC design.
In a plain vanilla CMOS process which does not have a deep-NWELL, we do not have the option of connecting the body to the source. Even if a deep-NWELL is supported, it will increase the area of the design because an extra deep-NWELL needs to be added and there would be some spacing constraints associated with it. If you are ok with the area increase, you can connect it to the source. This will reduce the VTH of the NMOS and depending on your biasing constraints, if you want to reduce VTH, you can do this.

Lastly, you need to consider the drain-bulk capacitance. When you connect bulk to ground, this cap is between drain and ground otherwise, it is between drain and source. So, in transient simulations of your circuit, you need to check which one is more desirable.

Comment: For my case, there is a different application. If we connect Body to source , VTH will be lower but there is some other different application being carried out. Its for IC design.

Comment: If your application is such that you find connecting bulk to source is preferable, go ahead and use it. Just make sure that the process allows it and that you are ok with the area penalty.